# Lagrangian of simple harmonic oscillator on a moving platform

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, spring

I came across the following example

> Consider a mass-spring system, mass $m$ and spring stiffness $k$, contained within a
> massless cart which is translating horizontally with a fixed velocity $U$ —see
> Figure 2.3. The constant velocity $U$ of the cart is maintained by an external agent. The Lagrangian $L = T − V$ for this system is:$$L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot q^2-\frac{1}{2}k(q-Ut)^2$$
> [image: 1]

I think there may be a mistake in the given figure (2.3) and I have marked what I think should be $Ut$ and not what is given:

Now, shouldn't $(q-Ut)$ be the elongation or compression from the equilibrium position and not from the thing? And then that is why $Ut$ should be what I have marked instead of what is given in the figure? Or is there a mistake in my understanding?

Comment: You are right. But the example shown sets the equilibrium position to zero implicitly.

Comment: How can the equilibrium position match the position where the spring is fixed?

Comment: what is the “thing”?

Comment: To which the spring is attached.